# Redmine connecting to SVN through SSL

Tags: ruby, svn, ssl, redmine

I am having trouble connecting Redmine to a locally hosted subversion repository using SSL.

I suspect it's the self-signed certificate that usually triggers a warning in the SVN client and browser.

When I try to connect to the local repo through SSL in Redmine, I get a red "Revision not available" error. When I try connecting through `svn://`, the connection times out, and I have to restart the web server.

Connecting without SSL works without problems.

It would be nice to run subversion on SSL to make it safely accessible from the outside as well. I could run the repository through plain HTTP but would like SSL for outside communication. As far as I understand, subversion can't be run both ways at the same time.

Does anybody know what to do in such a situation? Is there a configuration setting to ignore invalid certificates somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source all redmine does is shell out to the svn binary, see: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/trunk/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/subversion_adapter.rb

So if you can somehow workout how to get the binary to accept your SSL certificate then you will be good.

From http://groups.google.com/group/bitten/browse_thread/thread/d18b21a703c68344?pli=1 it seems you need some manual interaction with svn to accept the cert.

So my suggestion: run svn checkout against your repo as the user running redmine and permanently accept the cert

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this message is because the default user under which redmine is running (www-data) calls the “svn” client to communicate with the repositories but the client replies back to it saying that the certificate is untrusted, thus the connection is closed.

Here's a step by step fix:
http://haknick.tumblr.com/post/2380507902/redmine-svn-subversion-certificate-issue-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

since you control both the client and the server,  is having the client accept the server certificate's issuing authority an option?

if it isn't a permanent option, at least you'd know if it was the problem if you did it temporarily.